# iPad > Appcelerator > Alloy > How to load a different view for a specific controller?

Tags: ipad, titanium, appcelerator

Hopefully quick question...I just cannot find this in the doc which may mean I shouldn't do it.

Let's say I have a "source" controller and a "source" view.

Typically I would do something like this:

```
var sources = Alloy.createController('source');
$.index.add(sources.getView());
```

Now, I want sources to have different views based on the orientation of the ipad. But it's still the same information, just laid out a little different.

I thought I might be able to do something like this:

```
var sources = Alloy.createController('source');
Ti.Gestures.addEventListener( "orientationchange", function(){
    if(Ti.Gestures.isPortrait()){
       $.index.add( sources.getView('sources/portrait') );
    }else{
       $.index.add( sources.getView('sources/landscape') );
    }
});
```

Obviously I would have to remove views I'm not using, but this is the general idea.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I could hide and show different elements in my single view as they are needed. Would this be the correct way to do this?

Comment: Try add multiple top level views in a xml markup. Get them using their ID's like `sources.getView('viewId')`. However, since you are displaying the same info but different layout, why not just change layout of the view when orientation changed?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend the later approach (hiding/showing) as opposed to adding more views to the stack. Think about a traditional HTML webpage with AJAX and responsive designs - you would do this with JS/CSS and not reload the page.

Assume you want an extra View for landscape ONLY

XML:
`<View id="ExtraLandscapeView">...<View>`

TSS:
    `"#ExtraLandscapeView" : { /* Styles here */ }`

JS:

```
if(Ti.Gestures.isPortrait()){
    $.ExtraLandscapeView.visible = false;
} else{
   $.ExtraLandscapeView.visible = true;
}
```